# Error while generating authentication token in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have created an endpoint localhost:8000/getauthtoken to generate the authentication token.

The curl command that i am using to get the authentication token is:

```
curl --request POST --url localhost:8000/getauthtoken --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"username":"admin", "password":"admin123"}'
```

But i am getting

```
{"password":["This field is required."],"username":["This field is required."]}
```

But in the command i am passing both username and password

As per the DRF documentation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/  this is the correct way.

Comment: It seems to be correct. Are you able to register new users?

Answer (score 5):

Use httpie (available on pypi)
Then follow this on terminal:

```
Http post your_ip:your_port/your_authresource/ username='' password=''
```

Or you can try that in Curl in right way:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/ -d "password=aaaaa&username=user"
```